# Ignore formatting certain sections in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010, nvelocity

I know a lot have asked about how to tweak the formatting options in Visual Studio, but is there a way to instruct Visual Studio to ignore certain sections of a document?

My problem is that I have a Velocity template, but Visual Studio does not know how to format the specific tags, which ends up making the template invalid.

In Visual Studio, I have associated my templates with the HTML editor, but is there another way to get syntax highlighting?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [CVSI](http://jonorossi.com/projects/cvsi/), although I don't think it currently supports VS2010, but you can always [send a patch to make it work](https://github.com/jonorossi/cvsi) ;-)

Comment: Cool! I actually saw that, but it didn't support VS2010, the current trunk does however. I'll check it out later.

Comment: I took a look at the trunk, but it didn't really seem to be able to do what I wan't... Sorry...